# MobileNetV2 preprocessing inconsistence on TF 2.2

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, mobilenet

In this [segmentation tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation), the preprocessing normalizes image values into `[0, 1]`.

However, according to the document of MobileNetV2 (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/mobilenet_v2/preprocess_input), the preprocess step normalizes data to the interval `[-1, 1]`.

Which preprocessing is the correct one and why?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to train your own network from scratch, you can apply any normalization you see fit, or even no normalization at all, it's your choice!

If, instead, you want to reuse the pretrained models (e.g.: by setting `weights='imagenet'` in the definition of `MobileNetV2`), then you **should** use the specific preprocessing in https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/mobilenet_v2/preprocess_input, since this model has been trained with this specific preprocessing (normalization to `[-1, 1]`).

Although you **should**, you could also treat the `MobileNetV2` pretrained model as a static blackbox transformation, and plug in any normalization you want. The downside: you could almost surely make better use of this black box by applying the standard normalization.

Comment: but the segmentation tutorial is also using the pre-trained weight

Comment: In fact if you train network you may use some range of normalization, usually between [-3, 3], and it is for that any input have very large differences than other. If you have already trained network, you must use normalization same as used to train this network.

Comment: If that is the case, then the right thing would be to set the normalization to [-1,1]. Setting it to `[0,1]` would be to use the `MobilenetV2` blackbox in a 'custom' way. It is still useful, because you are training a network after that blackbox, but it would probably be more beneficial to use the standard `preprocess_input`.